# Laravel Nova Metrics Value format not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-nova

I can't seem to get Nova's formatting for the Value Metrics to work. Simply nothing happens when I add the property to my return.

Any hints on what might be wrong?

```
$total = DB::table(hello')->sum(DB::raw('bye'));
return $this->result($total)->format("0,0");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return an object, an example:

```
return (new ValueResult($total))
            ->currency('$ ')
            ->format('0,0');
```